# Unlimited range for plot in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-named-ranges

I would like to create a plot whose range extends as new columns of data are added.
I have read that dynamic named ranges are not available in Sheets, and that named ranges are not allowed in plot definitions.
My data range does not start in column A but, say, in column P. I would be happy if it could extend indefinitely. In the case of a single row, this can be achieved by using, e.g.,
`P2:2`
but the data range for the plot requires more than one row. Is there a similar syntax I could use here ?

Comment: do you have a set amount of rows? If you do, then you can just do `P2:10`.

Comment: So simple ! How could I miss it ? Thx